# How to start Emacs with cursor at the end of a given file?

Tags: emacs

Is there a build-in in emacs to open a file at the end? So without using a wc first, and then using the output to do

> emacs +nboflines filename

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but the command M-> moves the view to the end of the file when it has been open.

Comment: Emacs isn't vim. Usually you don't open a file from a terminal in Emacs.
You can open a terminal from a file in Emacs.
Even better, use `dired` for navigation. You can assign a shortcut in `dired` to scroll to the end.

Comment: @abo-abo Why not open a file from a terminal in Emacs?

Comment: You can do it, of course. But then I assume that you use `ls` and `cd` for navigation.
`dired` is much more efficient. Even for opening a file, `ido` completion that you can get is
better than tab completion from bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silly (but working) answwer:

```
emacs +10000000 filename
```

Adjust the 10000000 if you have files with more lines than that.

Another way of doing it:

```
 emacs filename --eval "(goto-char (point-max))"
```

Note that the `--eval` ... is after the filename, as order matters here.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute the following command to move the pointer to the end of the buffer:

```
M-x end-of-buffer
```

And you can also create the following function in your .emacs file, adding a hook on *find-file-hook* which will execute our function for every file opened. That will always open a file in emacs with the pointer at the bottom of the buffer:

```
;; Bottom-line function:
(defun bottom-line ()
  "Opens a file with the pointer at the bottom line."
  (interactive)
  (end-of-buffer))

;; Hook for every file opened, execute the bottom-line function:
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'bottom-line)
```

Comment: Cool, but how can I specify a list of files that this applies to?;)